# Создание таблицы с 2 колонками

Tags: android, android-layout

Я делаю приложение по типу словаря. Нужно создать таблицу с двумя колонками, в первой - слово, во второй - перевод. Данные берутся из базы данных и запоняются в таблицу во время исполнения. Также нужно иметь возможность выделить элемент для удаления или редактирования (хотелось бы иметы возможность чтобы выделялась вся строка). Подскажите пожалуйста, что лучше использовать для реализация всего выше перечисленного.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для вас подходит обычная реализация `RecyclerView`, а каждый элемент уже будет состоять из обычного `LinearLayout` горизонтального, у которого есть левая и правая части. Адаптер будет заполнять каждый элемент слева и справа.